# how to handle the delete cmd in batch file in case of file does not exist for delete

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I have written batch file to delete a .zip extension file after 70 days we below

`forfiles /p "%SourceFolderLocation%" /s /m *.zip /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -%NumberOfDaysForFolderToExists%`

I am using this batch file in Jenkis Job. whenever the delete batch file is not getting the specified file which is older than specified date then jenkins job is failing.

Do we have any way to stop the jenkins job fail if the file is not found to delete also?

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: What is the error that is present in the Console Output of the job?  In your question, you state that when "the delete batch file is not getting the ... then the Jenkins job fails".  But then you ask if there is any way to fail the job if the file is not found... It seems like you are asking for the behavior that is already being exhibited.  Do you want the Jenkins job to succeed if there are no files to be deleted?

Comment: @JohnBartels- yes in both case it should pass the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ForFiles` Return values](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html):

> If `ForFiles` finds one or more matches if will return `Errorlevel` =0
>   
> If `ForFiles` finds no matches if will return `Errorlevel` =1 and
>   will print "*ERROR: No files found with the specified search
>   criteria*."

- [Suppress `forfiles` command error message](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) as `2>NUL forfiles  /p …`, *or*
- Force `Errorlevel` to 0, e.g. by `(call )` command, *and/or*
- [Force your script to return `Errorlevel` of 0](http://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) by `exit /B 0` command.

The whole script could be as follows (if `forfiles` is *the only cause* of Jenkins job fail):

```
rem … (previous commands here)
2>NUL forfiles /p "%SourceFolderLocation%" /s /m *.zip /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -%NumberOfDaysForFolderToExists%
(call )
rem … (next commands here)
exit /B 0
```

For the `(call )` trick explanation, see Dave Benham's reply to [*setting ERRORLEVEL to 0*](https://superuser.com/a/649329/376602) question:

> If you want to force the errorlevel to 0, then you can use this
>   totally non-intuitive, but very effective syntax: `(call )`. The space
>   after *call* is critical. If you want to set the errorlevel to 1, you
>   can use `(call)`. It is critical that there not be any space after
>   *call*.